# Add multiple objects to an array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

just getting back into coding after a long break, and picking up Objective C.

I want to add multiple objects to an array.  I can do it explicitly (as below) but I'm sure there must a smarter, iterative way to do it.

```
NSMutableArray *a =[NSMutableArray array];

Class A *c1 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[c1 setVAlueX:5];
[c1 setValueY:3];
[a addobject:c1];

Class A *c2 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[c2 setVAlueX:5];
[c2 setValueY:3];
[a addobject:c2];

Class A *c3 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[c3 setVAlueX:5];
[c3 setValueY:3];
[a addobject:c3];
```

etc

Comment: Take a look at [loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop).

Comment: Sorry but it is very unclear what exactly you are after.

Comment: just looking for a more efficient way to populate the array by providing a list of values rather than typing it all out multiple times.  The answer below makes sense to me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is nice and short:

```
NSArray *a = @[[A aWithX:5 Y:3], [A aWithX:5 Y:3], [A aWithX:5 Y:3]];
```

You'll have to implement a convenience constructor in class A:

```
+ (instancetype)aWithX:(int)x Y:(int)y
{
    A *a = [[self alloc] init];
    [a setValueX:x];
    [a setValueY:y];
}
```

Comment: Just if you wonder why the array gets created with @[ ]: that is a literal. you can read more about in in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html). is quite handy

Comment: like it.  I knew there had to be a way to do it.  Hadn't realised you could do that with a literal.  Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *a =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *b =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *c =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dictA = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dictB = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dictC = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

Class A *c1 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[dictA setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"] forKey:@"ID1"];
[dictA setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"] forKey:@"ID1"];
//[c1 setVAlueX:5];
//[c1 setValueY:3];
[a addobject: dictA];

Class A *c2 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[dictB setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"] forKey:@"ID1"];
[dictB setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"] forKey:@"ID1"];
//[c2 setVAlueX:5];
//[c2 setValueY:3];
[a addobject: dictB];

Class A *c3 = [[Class A alloc]init];
[dictC setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"5"] forKey:@"ID1"];
[dictC setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"3"] forKey:@"ID1"];
//[c3 setVAlueX:5];
//[c3 setValueY:3];
[a addobject: dictC];
```